# Pair monthly data with daily data

Tags: date-and-time, financialdata

I need to pair 30-year treasury yield data (only available monthly) to S&P500 data of the same dates.

Treasury data WolframAlpha accesses from the St. Louis Federal Reserve comes down with dates in a `DateList` format.

```
tb = WolframAlpha["United States 30 year treasury bond monthly", {{"History:Treasury:EconomicData", 1}, "TimeSeriesData"}];

Length@tb
460
```

As the S&P monthly data comes down with first of month data and the treasury data comes down with end of month data, I down load daily S&P data and convert the `TimeSeries` formatted dates to `DateList` format with the following function:

```
getSPData[dateStart_, dateEnd_, type_] := Module[{data, dates},
  data = FinancialData["SP500", {dateStart, dateEnd, type}];
  dates = DateList[#] & /@ data["Dates"];
  Transpose[{dates, data["Values"]}]]

sp = getSPData["Jan. 1, 1978", "Jan. 1, 2023", "Daily"];

Length@sp
11349
```

The `Intersection` of the dates gives me:

```
Intersection[tb[[All, 1]], sp[[All, 1]]];
Length@%
287
```

I can't remember and can't find how to use the `Intersection` of the dates to extract the S&P prices to pair them with the treasury data yields for the simulation I then need to run.

I came down with Covid the first of the year, and it has left me with some brain fog.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to check out [TimeSeriesResample](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html); it's the only built-in that I'm familiar with which takes "Intersection" as an argument. Also, I think that the first series is a [QuantityArray](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityArray.html) which could possibly make things unecessarily hard for you during resampling, so I'd strip away the values just to be on the safe side, however I'm not sure if that'd be a prob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming each dataset does not have duplicate dates:

```
DeleteCases[GroupBy[Join[tb, sp], First -> Last], {_}] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {0.0143332, 287} *)
```

```
Select[GroupBy[Join[tb, sp], First -> Last], Length[#] == 2 &] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {0.0195033, 287} *)
```

Or with `Association` (without assumption, first duplicate entries will be discarded):

```
tba = AssociationThread @@ Transpose @ tb;
spa = AssociationThread @@ Transpose @ sp;

DeleteCases[Merge[{tba, spa}, Join], {_}] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {0.0131367, 287} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below we define the variables `tb` and `sp500` that correspond to the t-bills and the S&P 500 data, respectively:

```
tb = WolframAlpha["United States 30 year treasury bond monthly",{{"History:Treasury:EconomicData", 1}, "TimeSeriesData"}];
sp500 = FinancialData["SP500", {"Jan. 1, 1978", "Jan. 1, 2023", "Daily"}];
```

Running some diagnostic tests on them, to get acquainted with the data, yields

[image]

The main take-away from this preliminary review of the data is that

1. the t-bills (`tb`) have significantly fewer data points (460 vs 11.349) however
2. they cover a slightly wider time range (approx. 45 years vs 44 years) also
3. they are shaped as a list of `Quantity` values ("Percent" or "%") while the S&P 500 data come in a `TemporalData` object (prob. a `TimeSeries`)

With that in mind, we should consider two possible ways forward: if we use the *"Times"* of `tb` as a pivot, then the `sp500` will have to *extrapolate* its values outside its time range (remember how the `sp500` has a narrower time range) and if we don't know *how* to extrapolate or if we *don't want to*, we'll have to restrict ourselves to the (*marginally*) shorter time span of `tb`.

Before treating each case separately, we will bundle the data together into a `TemporalData` object:

```
paths={tb[[All,-1]]//QuantityArray/*QuantityMagnitude,sp500["Values"]};
times={{tb[[All,1]]},{sp500["Times"]}};
td=TemporalData[paths,times,"MetaInformation"->{"Series"->{"tb","sp500"}}];
```

A quick view of our data does not seem to contradict our preliminary analysis:

```
td // separatePlot/*(Row[#, Spacer[10]] &)
```

[image]

### Case 1. - Pivot on `tb`, extrapolate `sp500`

Evaluating the following lines will produce several `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` `Message`s letting us know how *`Input value {xxxx} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used`*; this should come as no surprise since we're using `TimeSeriesResample[#,{"Times",1}]&` which pivots on the times of series component 1 ie `tb`, which covers a wider range than `sp500` (remember our preliminary diagnostics).

```
tdR1=td//(TimeSeriesResample[#,{"Times",1}]&)/*(TemporalData[#,"MetaInformation"->{"Series"->(#["Series"]//Map[StringJoin[#,"-","R1"]&])}]&)

tdR1//separatePlot(tdR1["Series"]//Map[style])->(tdR1["Components"]//Apply[runDiagnostics/*Values])//AssociationThread/*(TakeDrop[#,1]&)/*Map[Dataset]/*(Row[#,Spacer[10]]&)
```

[image]

[image]

Looking at the diagnostics, we can verify that both series have the same number of observations (460), the span the same time range (approx. 46 years) and have the same time increment (2.592.000 or  60x60x24x30 *s* or 30 days).

### Case 2. - Intersection

This time, there are no `Message`s generated since no extrapolation is required. `TimeSeriesResample[#,"Intersection"]&` uses the intersection of times present in the two series. However, since the time span of the `sp500` is slightly shorter than the one for `tb`, the new range is shorter than the one in Case 1. Also, both series have significantly less observations (287 instead of 460).

```
tdR2=td//(TimeSeriesResample[#,"Intersection"]&)/*(TemporalData[#,"MetaInformation" -> {"Series" -> (#["Series"] // Map[StringJoin[#, "-", "R2"] &])}] &)
tdR2//separatePlot(tdR2["Series"]//Map[style])->(tdR2["Components"]//Apply[runDiagnostics/*Values])//AssociationThread/*(TakeDrop[#,1]&)/*Map[Dataset]/*(Row[#,Spacer[10]]&)
```

[image]

[image]

---

### Diagnostics

`runDiagnostics` recursively runs `diagnostics` on its arguments and reports the result.

```
ClearAll[runDiagnostics]
SetAttributes[runDiagnostics,HoldAll]
runDiagnostics[]:=<||>
runDiagnostics[expr_,rest___]:=Join[<|diagnostics[expr]|>,runDiagnostics[rest]]
```

`diagnostics` delivers a number of tests on a data object it operates on; its arguments so far can be lists of time-value lists or `TemporalData` objects. It performs the tests by applying `diagf` which in turn depends on `fs` for the actual content of the tests to deliver.

```
ClearAll[diagnostics]
SetAttributes[diagnostics,HoldFirst]
With[{color=ColorData[97,"ColorList"][[1]]},
 diagnostics[expr_,style_:(Style[#,Bold,color]&)]:=Through[Rule[Identity/*style,ReleaseHold/*diagf][HoldForm@expr]]
]
```

The purpose of `diagf` is to act as an appropriate container for the functions in `fs`.

```
ClearAll[diagf]
diagf=Function[expr,expr//(Through[ReleaseHold[fs][#]]&)/*(Thread[fs->#]&)/*Association,HoldFirst];
```

`fs` holds a `List` of the auxiliary functions, defined in the section below; it is used in `diagf` above.

```
fs={HoldForm@Length[Data],HoldForm@TemporalRegularity[Data],HoldForm@Missing[Data],MinimumTimeIncrement,HoldForm@First[Time],HoldForm@Last[Time],HoldForm@Range[Time],HoldForm@First[Value],HoldForm@Last[Value]};
```

### Auxiliary definitions

The following definitions are mostly `UpValues` defined for the symbol `Time`; they evaluate to different functions, depending on the `Head` of their input expression; they are designed to operate on `List`s and `TemporalData`, for the time being.

```
ClearAll[Time]
Time/:First[Time]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,First/*First,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"FirstTime"]&)/*DateList])&
Time/:Last[Time]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,Last/*First,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"LastTime"]&)/*DateList])&

range=(Through[{First/*First,Last/*First}[#]]&)/*Apply[DateDifference[##,{"Year","Month","Day","Hour"}]&];
Time/:Range[Time]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,range,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"Paths"]&)/*Map[range]])&

ClearAll[Data]
Data/:Length[Data]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,Dimensions,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"Paths"]&)/*Map[Dimensions]])&
Data/:TemporalRegularity[Data]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,Missing["NotApplicable"],_TemporalData,RegularlySampledQ])&

count=Count[#,_?(Not[FreeQ[#,Missing]]&)]&;
Data/:Missing[Data]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,count,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"Paths"]&)/*Map[count]])&

ClearAll[Value]
Value/:First[Value]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,First/*Last,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"FirstValue"]&)])&
Value/:Last[Value]:=(#//Switch[#,_List,Last/*Last,_TemporalData,(Construct[#,"LastValue"]&)])&
```

The following are used for plotting data:

```
style=Style[#,Bold,ColorData[97,"ColorList"][[1]]]&;
epilog=(#["Path"]&)/*(Select[#,(FreeQ[#,Missing]&)]&)/*TimeSeries/*(MovingMap[Mean,#,{{12,"Month"},Center},"Fixed"]&)/*({Red,Opacity[.65],Line[#["Path"]]}&);
plot=DateListPlot[#1,Epilog->(#//epilog),FrameTicks->{{None,All},{Automatic,None}},ImageSize->Medium,PlotLabel->(#2//style)]&;
separatePlot=(Through[{Construct[#,"Components"]&,Construct[#,"Series"]&}[#]]&)/*(MapThread[plot,#]&);
```